# Questions regarding issues with Salesforce System Status

Tags: discussion

[New Developer Account?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9260/new-developer-account)

I came across the preceding question today and I wanted to know if this question was really relevant to the community in the long term. While I could see value in describing a specific issue when Salesforce pushes out a new release, I don't see any long term value (i.e beyond 24 hours) of a question that pertains the status of the platform on a specific day.

Should this post be voted down? Should I flag it for moderator attention? or is it relevant and should be left alone?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Such questions should be closed as off-topic http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219/questions-on-reporting-salesforce-bugs

Comment: @Saariko That answer really only pertains to bugs and "known issues"... This particular user was referencing the current state of the developer account registration system. I don't think that really falls under bugs or known issues... Do you?

Comment: It's a bug - a local bug. I don't think we need to have a history of the bugs SF had during the time/period. JMP

Answer (score -1):

I would just leave it. Sure, it is highly specific to a timeframe, but in a "long term perspective" a lot of questions about specific release features will also be unrelevant and incorrect in the future if these change.  The question referred to can easily be answered and in my opinion is not really prone to get into a discussion.

Somewhat similar scenario questions related to IDE problems with specific Java releases, dev console problems with browsers or versions, specific salesforce instance problems or bugs and how to deal with them have been received well. Sure, they will be meaningless in a year from now, but right now, and in the near future they are meaningful to a lot of people looking for answers to these issues.